# Ruby on Rails won't install on MacOS Sierra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I was following the instructions here: http://installrails.com/

(I also tried using rbenv instead of rvm)

After entering

```
sudo gem install rails
```

this is the error I get:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error installing rails:     ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/nokogiri-1.7.1/ext/nokogiri /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170417-52755-r3zm64.rb extconf.rb checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes checking if the C compiler accepts
-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no Building nokogiri using packaged libraries. Using mini_portile version
2.1.0 checking for iconv.h... yes checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes checking for iconv using --with-opt-* flags... yes
************************************************************************ IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.4 with the following patches applied:
    - 0001-Fix-comparison-with-root-node-in-xmlXPathCmpNodes.patch
    - 0002-Fix-XPointer-paths-beginning-with-range-to.patch
    - 0003-Disallow-namespace-nodes-in-XPointer-ranges.patch

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install

Note, however, that nokogiri is not fully compatible with arbitrary versions of libxml2 provided by OS/package vendors.
************************************************************************ Extracting libxml2-2.9.4.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.4... OK Running git apply with /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/nokogiri-1.7.1/patches/libxml2/0001-Fix-comparison-with-root-node-in-xmlXPathCmpNodes.patch... OK Running git apply with /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/nokogiri-1.7.1/patches/libxml2/0002-Fix-XPointer-paths-beginning-with-range-to.patch... OK Running git apply with /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/nokogiri-1.7.1/patches/libxml2/0003-Disallow-namespace-nodes-in-XPointer-ranges.patch... OK Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.9.4... OK Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.9.4... ERROR, review '/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/nokogiri-1.7.1/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.4/compile.log' to see what happened. Last lines are:
======================================================================== /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/make-0.3.1/bin/make:4:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `make' for main:Object (NameError)     from /usr/local/bin/make:22:in `load'   from /usr/local/bin/make:22:in `<main>'
========================================================================
*** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:     --with-opt-dir  --with-opt-include  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include    --with-opt-lib  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib    --with-make-prog    --without-make-prog     --srcdir=.  --curdir    --ruby=/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)   --help  --clean     --use-system-libraries  --enable-static     --disable-static    --with-zlib-dir     --without-zlib-dir  --with-zlib-include     --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include  --with-zlib-lib     --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib  --enable-cross-build    --disable-cross-build /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:366:in `block in execute': Failed to complete compile task (RuntimeError)   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:337:in `chdir'   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:337:in `execute'     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:111:in `compile'     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:150:in `cook'    from extconf.rb:364:in `block (2 levels) in process_recipe'     from extconf.rb:257:in `block in chdir_for_build'   from extconf.rb:256:in `chdir'  from extconf.rb:256:in `chdir_for_build'    from extconf.rb:363:in `block in process_recipe'    from extconf.rb:262:in `tap'    from extconf.rb:262:in `process_recipe'     from extconf.rb:547:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.4.0/nokogiri-1.7.1/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/nokogiri-1.7.1 for inspection. Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.4.0/nokogiri-1.7.1/gem_make.out
```

And the mkmf.log file says

```
"clang -o conftest
-I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe  conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/lib
-L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib     -lruby.2.4.0  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc  " checked program was: /* begin */ 1: #include "ruby.h" 2:  3: int main(int argc, char **argv) 4: { 5:   return 0; 6: } /* end */

"clang
-I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe    -Werror -c conftest.c" checked program was: /* begin */ 1: #include "ruby.h" 2:  3: int main() {return 0;} /* end */

"clang
-I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe  -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future   -Werror -c conftest.c" error: unknown warning option '-Werror=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future'; did you mean '-Werror=unused-command-line-argument'? [-Werror,-Wunknown-warning-option] checked program was: /* begin */ 1:
#include "ruby.h" 2:  3: int main() {return 0;} /* end */

have_header: checking for iconv.h... -------------------- yes

"clang -E
-I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe   conftest.c -o conftest.i" checked program was: /* begin */ 1: #include "ruby.h" 2:  3: #include <iconv.h> /* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for gzdopen() in -lz... -------------------- yes

"clang -o conftest
-I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe  conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/lib
-L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib     -lruby.2.4.0 -lz  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc  " checked program was: /* begin */  1: #include "ruby.h"  2:   3: #include <zlib.h>  4:   5: /*top*/  6: extern int t(void);  7: int main(int argc, char **argv)  8: {  9:   if (argc > 1000000) { 10:     printf("%p", &t); 11:   } 12:  13:   return 0; 14: } 15: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))gzdopen; return !p; } /* end
*/

--------------------

have_iconv?: checking for iconv using --with-opt-* flags...
-------------------- yes

"clang -o conftest
-I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe  conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/lib
-L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib     -lruby.2.4.0  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc  " Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_iconv", referenced from:
      _main in conftest-d8bec7.o   "_iconv_open", referenced from:
      _main in conftest-d8bec7.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) checked program was: /* begin */  1:
#include "ruby.h"  2:   3: #include <stdlib.h>  4: #include <iconv.h>  5:   6: int main(void)  7: {  8:     iconv_t cd = iconv_open("", "");  9:     iconv(cd, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL); 10:     return EXIT_SUCCESS; 11: } /* end */

"clang -o conftest
-I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/x86_64-darwin15 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe  conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/lib
-L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib     -lruby.2.4.0 -liconv -lpthread -ldl -lobjc  " checked program was: /* begin */  1: #include "ruby.h"  2:   3: #include <stdlib.h>  4: #include <iconv.h>  5:   6: int main(void)  7: {  8:     iconv_t cd = iconv_open("", "");  9:     iconv(cd, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL); 10:     return EXIT_SUCCESS; 11: } /* end */

--------------------
```

I feel like I've tried everything- please help!

Comment: Did you install xcode command line tools?

Comment: I just updated to sierra and had to reinstall xcode to get nokogiri or anthing really to compile. Just installing the app is enough as it installs most header files. You only really need the command line tools if you want to compile Objective-C or Swift. After installing xcode running `gem install nokogiri` should work perfectly fine without the `--use-system-libraries` option.

Comment: xcode is up to date and i've installed CLT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling everything. It was coming from an issue with make. Resolved here: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3995

Answer (score 0):

Try installing nokogiri manually

```
brew install libxml2 libxslt

gem install nokogiri -v '1.7.1' -- --use-system-libraries --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include/libxml2
```

Comment: still getting "ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension." and "make failed, exit code 1"

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see if Command Line tools are installed? A lot of times Nokogiri won't install if the there is no c compiler.

type: `$ xcode-select -p`

If you see: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` The full Xcode package is already installed.

type `gcc`
You  should see an alert box:
[image]

Alternatively, you can use a command to install Xcode Command Line Tools. It will produce a similar alert box. **Note:** the double hyphen:

`$ xcode-select --install`

That might help